# Deleting a key from a Dictionary using a nested loop, then updating the dictionary

Tags: python

Hi I have this dictionary that I want to delete a key. However, it updates in the loop but not outside it. The example is part of my code. Thanks in advance!

```
while True:
  mydict = {'apples': 10, 'oranges': 20}
  choice = int(input("please enter a number"))
  if choice == 4:  
    name = input("what is the name of the item you want to delete?")
    if name in mydict:  
        del mydict[name]  
        print(name, "deleted")
        print(mydict)
    else:
      print("hi")
  elif choice == 5:
    print(mydict)
  else:
    print("hi")
```

So when the user chooses choice as 5, the dictionary is still the same

Comment: When the input is converted to 5, there is nothing in the code that would modify the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

It updates the dictionary in the loop only, because you have declared that dictionary in the loop.

To fix your issue, simply declare the dictionary outside of your while loop.

Also, do some reading on scoping :). This will explain why this is happening better.

Comment: thanks so much, honestly i spent ages trying to figure it out....

Comment: glad to have helped!